# How i can cancel editing datagridview by clicking button if dataerror?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have DataGridView and button.

```
DataGridView myDataGridView = new DataGridView();
Button cancelBtn = new Button();
```

I subscribe on event

```
myDataGridView.DataError += myDataGridView_DataError;
cancelBtn.Click += cancelBtn_Click;
```

And my event handlers

```
void myDataGridView_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
//show error message
MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message);
//set to editing element original value
curRowDataGrid.CancelEdit();
}

void cancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
curRowDataGrid.CancelEdit();
//and some specific additional logic
}
```

But if i click on cancelBtn (if before clicking i wrote wrong value) I do not get to the event handler cancelBtn_Click, i get to myDataGridView_DataError and stay there.

I want following logic: no matter what I typed data if i click on cancelBtn i want get to cancelBtn_Click().

Answer (score 0):

Though the cancel button is clicked, before the click event of cancel button some un-handled exception in the page could have caused because of the wrong data you have provided,  the request goes to the DataError Event handler. 
Better, implement proper exception handling in your code , suppress exceptions you don't want to fire.

Comment: or myDataGridView.CausesValidation = false